# More date format conversion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am working with SQL 2014 and I need to convert the following 2 date formats:

```
12/31/18 - Varchar 
12/31/2018 - Varchar
```

to this format final format

```
December 31,2018 Varchar
```

I know that use varchar is not the correct.
any suggestion?

Comment: I think the best way would be to cast to date an then convert to varchar. Try to looked for `CAST` and `CONVERT`in the documentation.

Comment: Don't do it!  Just convert to a `date` and then store that value in the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use:

```
DECLARE @f varchar(50) = '12/31/18'
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@f AS DATETIME), N'MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

OUTPUT:

```
December 31, 2018
```

And your second variant:

```
DECLARE @f varchar(50) = '12/31/2018'
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@f AS DATETIME), N'MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

OUTPUT:

```
December 31, 2018
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query also using

```
create table DateValue (DateVal varchar(10))
insert into DateValue values
('12/31/18'),
('12/31/2018'),
('01/31/18'),
('01/31/2018')

Select 
    DateName( month , DateAdd( month , DATEPART(MONTH, DateVal) , 0 ) - 1 ) + ' ' +
    Cast(DATEPART(dd, DateVal) as Varchar)  + ', ' +
    + Cast (DATEPART(YYYY, DateVal) as Varchar) as VarcharDate
from DateValue
```

The output will be as shown below.

```
VarcharDate
----------------
December 31, 2018
December 31, 2018
January 31, 2018
January 31, 2018
```

This query will also run in lower version of SQL Server where `format()` is not available.

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/GWDY11248)